# Tomcat 7: Invalid mapping (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, tomcat7, web.xml

I am migrating an existing project from Tomcat 6 to 7. Upon startup I am encountering this logged error message:

```
Jul 02, 2013 2:38:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig parseWebXml
SEVERE: Parse error in application web.xml file at jndi:/localhost/padd/WEB-INF/web.xml
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: jndi:/localhost/padd/WEB-INF/web.xml; lineNumber: 309; columnNumber: 21; Error at (309, 21) : The servlets named [ArtefactServlet] and [saveArtefactServlet] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/saveRestoration] which is not permitted
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2687)
    ...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [ArtefactServlet] and [saveArtefactServlet] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/saveRestoration] which is not permitted
```

Here the **WEB-INF/web.xml** line 309fff:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>saveArtefactServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/saveRestoration</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

EDIT:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ArtefactServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/saveRestoration</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Here **tomcat's web.xml**:

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- The mappings for the JSP servlet -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

I tried to play around with the mapping, but couldn't make any progress. Hope you can help!

Comment: <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>saveArtefactServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/saveRestoration</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>  I think this has been duplicated. Please check another any occourences with same name exist in web.xml

Comment: In the we.xml file the servlet-name has been used multible times for different url-patterns. for tomcat 6 this was no problem, could this be the issue?

Comment: one servlet to many mappings ok, many servlets to one mapping, not ok

Comment: Can you please show servlet mapping for 'ArtefactServlet'

Comment: i added it to the question

Answer (score 4):

The error says :

> The servlets named [ArtefactServlet] and [saveArtefactServlet] are
>   both mapped to the url-pattern [/saveRestoration] which is not
>   permitted

So tomcat doesn't know which servlet to be called when your url pattern is matched. Give different url patterns for these two servlets **ArtefactServlet**, **saveArtefactServlet**

Comment: i guess this must be changed within the servlet itself incl. the url-pattern in the web.xml - correct?

Comment: in which file is your ArtefactServlet defined?

Comment: is it possible for you to change the pattern of artifact servlet to something else? like /artifactServet?

Comment: i just searched the code and the saveArtefactServlet doesn't seem to exist. ill commend it out and give it a try, thanks!

Comment: edit: the mappings point to various identical servlets. could this be a feature that i not supported within tomcat 7 any more?

Comment: its not possible. check out this link to know more about servlets and mappings. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/webapp/configureservlet.html

Comment: thank you for the link, i fixed the error and can continue with the correct pattern-recocnition!

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named...
```

I fetched this cause where I create new servlet in different package (name='syncro'). My servlet located in ***syncro.SynchronizeServlet***
And when I add information about this servlet in deployment descriptor (web.xml) I catch error: ***IllegalArgumentException***

Example of incorrect descriptor part:

```
<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>SynchronizeServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>SynchronizeServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>SynchronizeServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SynchronizeServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/SynchronizeServlet</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/SynServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

When I add correct path for servlet - error  disappeared. Correct desc below:

```
<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>syncro.SynchronizeServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>syncro.SynchronizeServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>syncro.SynchronizeServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>syncro.SynchronizeServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/SynchronizeServlet</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/SynServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

==> 73!